# OpenVPN on port 53

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server setup on UDP port 53 on a public IP. 
All the connecting clients gets pushed external DNS servers such as 8.8.8.8 (Google) and OpenDNS.

Sometimes the resolution stops working on the connected VPN clients and I get strange packets in the OpenVPN log. Now my question is why is that?

When a VPN client, let's say 192.168.1.22 does a DNS query that query should go to 8.8.8.8:53 and then an UDP response packet should be sent back to 192.168.1.22 on a high UDP port.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have an openvpn server setup on UDP port 53" <--- why?

Comment: Because most of the clients are roadwarriors, mobile devices which connect through various wifi networks which always have different firewall rules setup. I got the most success with using UDP port 53.

Comment: please post the "strange packets in the log" with your question. Also, the server and client configurations would be helpful.

Comment: I guess you configured NAT using iptables (or nftables). Could you provide the iptables configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The setup should work if it's configured right. The encapsulation works this way:

Original Packet (`DNS-Q`):

```
[src=YourIP_wlan0:udp/random1] [dst=Google:udp/53]
```

New Packet (`B`), after OpenVPN Process:

```
[src=YourIP_tun0:udp/random2] [dst=VPNserver:udp/53] [DNS-Q]
```

New Packet (`C`), after your WIFi provider NAT's:

```
[src=YourIP_Wifi:udp/random2] [dst=VPNserver:udp/53] [DNS-Q]
```

1. The packet gets sent to VPNserver via UDP/53 (encrypted).
2. VPNserver decrypts the packet, opens it, looks at the original layer 3 address and forwards it to it's default gateway (HomeRouter).
3. Before sending the packet, HomeRouter performs NAT. The packet now looks like this as it's sent over to Google:

   ```
   [src=HomeRouter_PublicIP:random_port1] [dst=Google:udp/53]
   ```
4. Google gets the packet, processes the DNS query, and replies with a DNS-REPLY to the HomeRouter_PublicIP (FYI this is NOT a DNS forward, it's just a NAT). The return packet (DNS-R) now looks like this:

   ```
   [src=Google:udp/53] [dst=HomeRouter_PublicIP: random_port1]
   ```
5. HomeRouter receives the reply packet and reverse NAT:

   ```
   [src=Google:udp/53] [dst=YourIP_tun0:random_port1]
   ```
6. HomeRouter forwards the packet to VPNserver.
7. VPNserver mangles the packet for encryption:

   ```
   [src=VPNserver:udp/53] [dst=YourIP_WiFi: random_port2] [DNS-R]
   ```
8. VPNserver sends the packet over the Internet.
9. Your machine receives the packet, and decrypts/decaps it to looks like this:

   ```
   [src=Google:udp/53] [dst=YourIP_wlan0: random_port1]
   ```
10. DNS resolution complete.

Answer (score -2):

Port 53 udp is reserved for DNS traffic. Even though you may have gotten OpenVPN to work on this port you are seriously blocking the server's ability to resolve DNS queries. I would strongly advise you to use a different port, one that is not in use by other services on that machine before even attempting to fix the issues you're seeing.

Comment: "seriously blocking the server's ability to resolve DNS queries" < The VPN server itself is not used for any other purpose. I don't care if it cannot resolve anything. My clients use external DNS servers as I said. Port 53 seems to be a nice choice to me.

Comment: "I don't care if it cannot resolve anything", so how then do you keep this server up to date with the latest security patches? If you're keen on using encrypted tunnels I think you should be even more keen to keep the system secure... Google Heartbleed for starters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment which isn't related to the subject AT ALL. If you aren't technical enough to answer this question precisely then don't say anything. I don't want to keep it up to date because there are no services running on it except openvpn and openssh and even openssh is binded to an internal ip which is only accessible from inside the vpn ...

Answer (score -2):

You need to check the main router in case there is a packet redirection. Any request to 53 gets routed to ISP DNS for example.